# connection closed when using cursor and procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, visual-studio, oracle11g

My code is-

```
        string oracleb = "Data source=HPPRO58; user ID=system; password=deb;";
        conn = new OracleConnection(oracleb);
        //conn.Open();
        conn.Open();
        String x3 = "google";
        String x1 ;
        String x2;
        String s1 = "delete from temp";
        OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(s1, conn);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();


        OracleCommand comm2 = new OracleCommand();
        String s2 = "cv";
        comm2.Connection = conn;
        comm2.CommandText = s2;
        comm2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm2.Parameters.Add("x", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox1.Text;
        comm2.Parameters.Add("y", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox2.Text;
        comm2.Parameters.Add("z", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Value = x3;
        comm2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        String s3 = "select * from temp";
        OracleCommand comm3 = new OracleCommand(s3, conn);
        OracleDataAdapter MyAdapter3 = new OracleDataAdapter();//adapter acts as interface btw database and dataset(which is collectio of tables)
        MyAdapter3.SelectCommand = comm;
        DataTable dTable3 = new DataTable();//datatable represents a single table in database 
        MyAdapter3.Fill(dTable3);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable3;
        conn.Close();
```

My error is-

[image]

I am trying to run a procedure which has a cursor too.Therefore I am using 3 comm variables.But I am getting the above error.Therefore I was wondering how to solve it.

I have opened the connection in the starting of the function but still it is showing connection is closed.

edit-

my procedure name is cv

new error-
[image]

my procedure-

```
create or replace procedure cv(x in int,y in int,z in varchar)
as
cursor c
is
select email,collegename,cgpa,compname
from student_cv
where (cgpa>=x and yearsofexp>=y) and compname=z;
tem c%rowtype;
begin
open c;
loop
fetch c into tem;
exit when c%notfound;
insert into temp values(tem.email,tem.collegename,tem.cgpa,tem.compname);
end loop;
end;
/
```

line 59 is-

```
comm2.Parameters.Add("x", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox1.Text;
```

Comment: I see your comm and comm3 are using the conn but your comm2 and comm3 I dont see you setting the conn to use anywhere?

Comment: Well spotted. That must be the culprit.

Comment: @Brad I did some changes and got new errors. line 59 is comm2.Parameters.Add("x", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox1.Text;

Comment: I dont think your using paramaters right, you need to put the paramater name in the text and set the value by using the paramanter set look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Brad I have added the procedure

Comment: Your SQL String s2 = "cv";  is not setup properly I do not beleive, at least for MSSQL, for Oracle not sure but the C# code does not look right, see the link I posted for passing paramaters (though I may be wrong with it being Oracle)

Comment: `"z", OracleType.Number` is wrong, it should be `OracleType.VarChar`

Comment: Please put your error message as text (Ctrl+C is your friend) not as image and tell us at which line you get the error.

Comment: Namespace `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet) for ages, you should not use it

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I tried copying the error it was not getting copied...I mentioned the line 59 is comm2.Parameters.Add("x", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox1.Text;

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit what should I put instead of System.Data.OracleClient ?

Comment: Try Oracle.DataAcces.Client